# Access Oracle SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I'm kinda stuck here. I have a small stupid function in Oracle and try to access it with Java. The return value should be an SYS_REFCURSOR. But I get an error if I try to call it in Java.

This is the Oracle function:

```
FUNCTION GET_TBL_AS_CUR
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  Tbl SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  OPEN Tbl FOR SELECT * FROM test_tbl;
  RETURN Tbl;

END;
```

This is the Call in Java:

```
String stmt = "callStmt: {?= call dbschema.pkg_tbl_tools.get_tbl_as_cur()}";
callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(stmt);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
System.out.println("Executing... " + stmt + "\n");

callableStatement.execute();

rs = ((OracleCallableStatement)callableStatement).getCursor(1);

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

The error message is:

```
Unknown SQL-Type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: On what line did you get the error message?  Was it the last line, where you call `getCursor`?

Comment: After the `getCursor` call nothing happens. Just the `catch(Exception)`. The error message shown is printed out there.

Comment: Does the PL/SQL function work in Oracle?  In the Java code, have you tried `getObject(1)` and casting what's returned to a `ResultSet`?

Comment: That's your actual `stmt`? It's invalid, but it's so wrong I'm not sure if you've mangled it creating the question. The error message is like nothing I've seen before too; perhaps the stack trace would help.

Comment: What's invalid? I'm quite sure that this works. Another function with a VARCHAR2 as return value works just fine.

Comment: Try using a pl sql block, A simple example, http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

Thanks for your help. To summarize the final "trick" I'll post here the solution.

This style of call will work for any function or procedure in Oracle **IF** the function will return not an collection as ref cursor.

```
String stmt = "{call ? := dbschema.pkg_tbl_tools.get_tbl_as_cur()}";
```

This style works in Oracle just fine, even if the return value is a ref cursor

```
String stmt = "BEGIN ? := dbschema.pkg_tbl_tools.get_tbl_as_cur(); END;";
```

The following line

```
rs = ((OracleCallableStatement)callableStatement).getCursor(1);
```

could be changed into

```
rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
```

Don't know why. But it works now. Thanks again :)

Comment: The `stmt` as you have it returns `ORA-00900`; I would expect it to look like `stmt = "{ call ? := dbschema....() }"'. Which is equivalent to your `BEGIN`/`END` version. My Oracle DB and driver don't know what to make of `callStmt: `, or the `?= call` rather than `call ? :=`. Are you using the JDBC driver directly, or is through a framework?

Comment: I'll only tested this on 12c Oracle. `BEGIN ...; END;` will work as well `{call ? := ... }`. The other combination I found on other sites and they may be most likely buillsh ;) I've edited my answer.